# CSS Handwriting Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a landing page for a client with their logo in the center and their catchphrase directly below - however they want the catch phrase to be animated so that it looks as though it is being handwritten.

I have been struggling for days with this and have no clue how to do it - if someone could help me it would be such a lifesaver!

Here is the basic landing page with no animation on the catchphrase:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
<a href="home.html">
<img src="http://japesfawcett.com/testsh/images/landing_logo2.png" />
</a>

<div id="test">
<p>enter the sunshine state</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
}

@font-face {
font-family: segoe;
src: url(fonts/segoesc.ttf);
}

div.image-wrapper {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image-wrapper img {
display: block;
}

#test {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#test p {
width: 100%;
font-family: segoe;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
color: #FAEDE8;
margin-top: -40px;
}
```

And a JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9297gefk/

Again, any help would be incredible!

Comment: Handwritten? You can either do it with SVG or with canvas.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? [Digital Handwriting](http://digitalplant.eu/digital_handwriting/)?

Comment: I am not sure it is not possible just with CSS only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've created a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/9297gefk/2/) of it, that will do the trick for you.

And for effect like this, using `HTML5` is really good option as you've being suggested to use `canvas`.

Here you can change `height` & `width` of `canvas` and your `CSS` as per your need.

**Source**: [**Handwriting Effect**](https://www.codementor.io/javascript/tutorial/how-to-make-a-write-on-effect-using-html5-canvas-and-javascript-only).

Comment: Nice one! Canvas is ideal solution for this.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I suspected using the canvas was going to be helpful, just wasn't sure where to start - but again, much appreciated.